# power bi RANKX returning 1 for all rows

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to give rank to each row in daily stock price details table to figure out previous day closing price:

[image: stock daily prices]

The code I use is:

```
rank = 
RANKX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(NSE_DAILY_REPORT),
        NSE_DAILY_REPORT[SYMBOL]="ADLABS"
    ), 
    MAX(NSE_DAILY_REPORT[TDATE]),,
    ASC
)
```

The problem is that it returns a rank of 1 for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `MAX(NSE_DAILY_REPORT[TDATE])` to `NSE_DAILY_REPORT[SCLOSE]`

The second argument expects an expression to compare to evaluations of that same expression in the filtered subset. Using MAX will yield that every record gets ranked in a set of just one record, hence the 1 for all rows.

Comment: that expression is to give Rank based on TDate, i need to get previous day close price for each row.

i took reference from an article https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Column-with-value-from-previous-day-row/td-p/606109

Comment: Are there multiple records for a single day given a single stock?

Comment: yes, table having multiple records for a single day. to tackle this, we applied filter to get only ADLABS stock price.

Comment: So when you filter on ADLABS and a single day you get a single record?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly your goal is to get the closing price of the day before?

In that case `RANKX()` is not necessary in contrast to the post you shared as an example. There they create ordinality by creating a ranking first and then perform a pretty inefficient calculation to get the previous in rank. There already is ordinality as you have a date column. Power BI already knows how to interpret that scale, so getting a value for a previous day does not need an additional ranking.

There's tons of posts around stack overflow dealing with this problem. Have a look around to learn more. For your particular problem, the solution will be a calculated column with code looking something like:

```
PreviousDay = 
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( NSE_DAILY_REPORT[SCLOSE] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( NSE_DAILY_REPORT, NSE_DAILY_REPORT[SYMBOL] ),
            NSE_DAILY_REPORT[TDATE] = EARLIER(NSE_DAILY_REPORT[TDATE]) - 1
        )
)
```

It will do the trick, but it still has some inefficiencies you can improve by looking through other examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757128/qoq-measures-in-power-bi/)